# How to send an email on finding bad data in a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

I have below EmployeeData table and due to some known reasons BAD data is getting inserted and i am working on code fix, but meanwhile i want to check for bad data until the fix is deployed. If you observe John has **1** for both **Active** and **IsEmpTermed** columns.

[image]

Currently i am running the below query to check for Bad data **manually** in SQL Server. I want to automate this task and send an email to me if it finds bad data i.e. **Active =1** and **IsEmpTermed =1**. What and How to do it?

`select * from EmployeeData Where Active=1 and IsEmpTermed = 1;`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched for this on this site and/or Google? There are several examples out there, and several ways you can do this. Is mail configured on your SQL Server to send mail? You could also setup an SSRS report with a subscription to send you the results of your query.

Comment: Declare the appropriate constraint and prevent the "bad" data from getting into the table. This will also let you more easily find your application logic problem.

Comment: @SS_DBA - I don't find the relevant one for my scenario. If you are talking about Database Mail, Yes, its configured. I can't use SSRS. Could you please provide me the steps/links as to how i can automate this task?

Comment: @SMor - Yes, currently i am working on it, but i need a temporary solution asap to monitor the bad data until the code fix is ready to go.

Comment: quick way would be use the @query argument when using sp_send_dbmail, put that code in a SQL Agent job and have it run at whatever frequency you want.

Comment: @TimMylott Could you post here any sample code which will be helpful for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way would be use the @query argument with [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and put that code in a SQL Server Agent Job.

Here's a simple example of what that sp_send_dbmail looks like:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = ''  --This is specific to your setup
   ,@recipients = 'your@email.com'
   ,@subject = 'This is the subject'
   ,@query = 'select EmpID, FirstName, LastName from EmployeeData Where Active=1 and IsEmpTermed = 1' --The query
   ,@execute_query_database = ''  --The name of your database goes here where the query should be executed
```

That will basically execute the query you specified in @query, dump the results into an email and send it to whomever is in @recipients

If you don't know what the @profile_name is for your server configuration you can run

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp;
```

That will return a list of the mail profiles configured on your server.  You will use the value from the "profile_name" column.  If there are multiples, this is something I can't tell you as it is specific to your server configuration.

Once you have all that defined and working by manually running it in SSMS, go [create a SQL Server Agent Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-transact-sql-job-step?view=sql-server-ver15) with a T-SQL step and add the "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail" code.  [Defined a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-schedule?view=sql-server-ver15) at whatever frequency you would like it to run.

A lot of times I'll code it to check if the data issue exists before sending an email, so it will only send an email when the data issue exists so it won't keep spamming me if there are no issues, something like this

```
--The IF EXISTS checks if the data issue exists before sending an email
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 'x' FROM dbname.dbo.EmployeeData Where Active=1 and IsEmpTermed = 1)
BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = ''  --This is specifc to your setup
           ,@recipients = 'your@email.com'
           ,@subject = 'This is the subject'
           ,@query = 'select EmpID, FirstName, LastName from EmployeeData Where Active=1 and IsEmpTermed = 1' --The query
           ,@execute_query_database = ''  --The name of your database goes here
END
```

Comment: Got the below error: The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 3 (2020-07-19T17:47:42). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.24.109:465).  ) Used servertype - SMTP, servername - smtp.gmail.com, port - 465

Comment: seems as though the server cannot establish a connection to the SMTP host.  Maybe start by checking firewall or log onto the server and see if you can ping the host, if not that obviously needs to be fixed.